# How do I load Google Maps JS API in PhoneGap to use it multiple times?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, cordova

I'm developing a PhoneGap application with multiple pages and some of them show a map.

Now what I'm trying to do is to load the Google Maps API when the page loads so I can access it whenever I need it. Now there are several options:

1. Load the script *without* a callback parameter in the URL `...(url)&callback=functionName` when the page loads
   **Result:** the google.maps object is created but it's almost empty. The functions are all missing.
2. Load the script *with* a callback parameter in the URL when the page loads
   **Result:** the functions in google.maps are all available, but when I create a Map, I only get an empty `<div style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;"></div>` inside the container element. So it seems it starts to create the map, but the rest is missing.
   The funny thing here is: it works perfectly in desktop browsers, but it does not in a phonegap application - doesn't matter if Android or iOS.
3. Load the script *with* a callback, but every time a map should be displayed
   **Result:** it seems to work, but an error/a warning in the console shows up, telling me there may occur unexpected problems if I load the Maps API more than once. Plus it creates unnecessary server requests which slow down the application.

Running option 2 in Ripple Emulator tells me that the application tries to open a `InAppBrowser` when I open a page that should display a map. I don't have much experience with `InAppBrowser`, so I don't know what this is trying to tell me or if it even is related to the problem...

Currently I'm including the script via a simple

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type ...
script.src = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/.....';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Does anyone know how to include and use the API in a case like this?
Also the parameters I want to pass to the `new google.maps.Map()` constructor differ. So I need a flexible way to do this.

Thanks for any help
Andreas

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I created a function that loads Maps and sets a flag that's true when Maps is loaded. I call this function every time I need Maps, but before including it I check that flag.